# Python: multiple requests.posts with GPIO.setup

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am using a Raspberry Pi and want to check if an input is high or low using GPIO. Based on that, I want to send a post request to a webserver. However, now it is looping which results in multiple calls to my webserver at the same time. How an I prevent that from happening, so that the post request is called only once? This is what I tried so far, but it is not solving the problem.

```
import requests
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

file = open("/home/pi/Documents/datalogger/data/datalog.csv", "a")
i=0
lastValue = ""
userId = 1


def update_value(status):
      print( status )
      file.write(str(datetime.now())+"\n")
      file.flush()
      url = 'https://mywebserver.nl/project/log/api'
      dload = {'userId': userId, 'status': status, 'datetime': datetime.now()}
      x = requests.post(url, params = dload)
      print(x.content)
      return status;

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    buttonState = GPIO.input(16)
    if buttonState == 0:
        if lastValue != "started":
            lastValue = update_value("started")
    else:
        if lastValue != "stopped":
            lastValue = update_value("stopped")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should remove multiple calls for the same state as it will only change the state if the state has changed,

```
import requests
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

file = open("/home/pi/Documents/datalogger/data/datalog.csv", "a")
i=0
lastValue = 0
userId = 1


def update_value(status):
      print( status )
      file.write(str(datetime.now())+"\n")
      file.flush()
      url = 'https://mywebserver.nl/project/log/api'
      dload = {'userId': userId, 'status': status, 'datetime': datetime.now()}
      x = requests.post(url, params = dload)
      print(x.content)
      return status;

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    buttonState = GPIO.input(16)
    if buttonState != lastValue:
        if lastValue:
            lastValue = update_value("stopped")
        else:
            lastValue = update_value("started")

    time.sleep(1)
```